# is there difference between mongodb count() and python builtin len()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

it seems that i got **2 differents results** using the mongodb `count()` and python `len()`

```
db.users.find({"adresse.coord":{"$within":{"$center":[[4.365041,36.743954],100]}}}).distinct("produit_up") 
Out[17]: 
[{u'avatar': {u'avctype': u'image/jpeg', 
u'orientation': u'portrait', 
u'photo': ObjectId('506f2ee93a5f3a0528ab8621')}, 
u'spec': {u'abus': 0, 
u'date': u'2012-10-05', 
u'description': u'brrrrrrrrrrr', 
u'id': u'tofla134946378579', 
u'namep': u'nokia 6230', 
u'nombre': 2, 
u'prix': 1000, 
u'tags': [u'nokia', u'6230', u'photo'], 
u'vendu': False}}, 
{u'avatar': {u'avctype': u'image/jpeg', 
u'orientation': u'portrait', 
u'photo': ObjectId('506867863a5f3a0ea84dcd6c')}, 
u'spec': {u'abus': 0, 
u'date': u'2012-09-30', 
u'description': u"portable tr\xe8s solide, peu servi, avec batterie d'une autonomie de 3 heures.", 
u'id': u'alucaard134901952647', 
u'namep': u'nokia 3310', 
u'nombre': 1, 
u'prix': 1000, 
u'tags': [u'portable', u'nokia', u'3310'], 
u'vendu': False}}, 
{u'avatar': {u'avctype': u'image/jpeg', 
u'orientation': u'portrait', 
u'photo': ObjectId('506f2b3e3a5f3a0b3c4731a9')}, 
u'spec': {u'abus': 0, 
u'date': u'2012-10-05', 
u'description': u'bzzzzzzzzzz', 
u'id': u'alucaard134946284638', 
u'namep': u'nokia 6230', 
u'nombre': 1, 
u'prix': 2000, 
u'tags': [u'nokia', u'nok', u'noki'], 
u'vendu': False}}] 

db.users.find({"adresse.coord":{"$within":{"$center":[[4.365041,36.743954],100]}}}).count() 
Out[18]: 2 

len(db.users.find({"adresse.coord":{"$within":{"$center":[[4.365041,36.743954],100]}}}).distinct("produit_up")) 
Out[19]: 3
```

Comment: The latter is different - ``distinct()`` is on the end, is that intentional?

Comment: it should give me 3 result, but the count is omitting one result, so why is that happening?

Comment: I first thought you meant the standard built-in sequence `.count()` method, based on your question title alone. :-P

Comment: sorry :D am bad in english :D

Comment: Is "produit_up" an array that's embedded into the document?

Comment: is there one per document? It looks like your query matches two documents, but they have three distinct "produit_up" values between them.  Why do you think this is inconsistent?  Both queries which return 3 are the same, the one that returns 2 is different.

Comment: yes, i just get the problems when using the embeeded documents, for example, the only way to match all sub documents queries is to use the aggregation framework!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mongodb [`.count()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.count) will perform a server-side query that only requests the total number of documents matched. It sends a count command in the query. MongoDB will only return an int to your client driver.

Using the python `len()` will perform a client-side count of the number of documents returned from the mongodb query. That means you are receiving the full documents from the database, and operating on them locally.

If you only need to know the count, then the first one is more efficient because the result is faster and smaller.

If you plan on using the resulting documents and also want to know the count, then save the results of the query to a variable, and use `len()` to check its size. That way you do not have to perform two queries to get the count + the actual docs.

This is the primary answer to your question about the difference between their usage. As others have pointed out, the queries that you are comparing are, themselves, different.

Answer (score 2):

Two of your queries use "distinct" but the third one does not - it just uses count().  I would not expect the same number of results from different types of queries.

Consider this example collection of students:

```
{name:"joe", class: ["biology","math"]}
{name:"jane", class: ["math", "english"]}

db.students.find().count()    
2
db.students.find().distinct("class")
["biology","math","english"]
len(db.students.find().distinct("class"))
3
```

Comment: ah thank you! so they're two different queries! because i thought that when the result gets Python, then it's all a pythonic way!

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp: Don't forget that with the `Cursor` object, you can continue to tack on more ORM commands, such as `distinct` or `count`. The query only executes once you start to evaluate its values from the iterator.

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp: Like I said in my answer, `count` is more efficient if you don't need the documents. Far less work and data has to be processed in the response from the server.

Comment: ah! because am a beginner, here is how i work: i make a query, then i use dictionnary/lists operation to try to extract the data that i want, i'm making a simple e-commerce project, when i'll finish it i'll share it :)

thank you again :)